# I have defined a the Path to included files but including them using the Defined Paths does not work

Tags: php, require

I am currently building a beginner project in PHP.
I am trying to define the File Paths inside initialize.php.

when I access the page, I get this error

> require_once(): Failed opening required './shared/staff_header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php7.2') in /homepages/36/d767628852/htdocs/phpstudy/learn/public/staff/index.php on line

I have tried to include the file using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and it works, but defining them does not work

Here is the code in initialize.php

```
define("PRIVATE_PATH", dirname(_FILE_));
define("PROJECT_PATH", dirname(PRIVATE_PATH));
define("PUBLIC_PATH", PROJECT_PATH .'/public');
define("SHARED_PATH", PRIVATE_PATH .'/shared');
```

Here is my index.php

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/private/initialize.php';
$page_title = "Staff Menu";
require_once(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_header.php');
```

I then get this error

> require_once(): Failed opening required './shared/staff_header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php7.2') in /homepages/36/d767628852/htdocs/phpstudy/learn/public/staff/index.php on line

Comment: There's no way you could get a leading dot `.` from `dirname(__FILE__)` so there must be more to this code.

Comment: It should be `__FILE__` not `_FILE_` (two underscores on each side instead of one), so it's probably failing.

Comment: Cool! that went smooth! __FILE__ solved it